# rsyslogd as a syslog forwarder over TLS (certificate based authentication required)

Tags: linux, rhel, ssl, certificates, rsyslogd

I want to configure a machines rsyslogd (redhat OS7 in this case) to connect via TLS to a central log collector.
The resyslogd needs to authenticate with a client certificate.
I already have the key, certificate and the CA certificates (including intermediate CA) available.

But I do not find a decent configuration example to set this up.
I got completely lost with StreamDriver. 
I want to use the rsyslogd as a syslog forwarder of its local configured log events over TLS to a central log collector. And certifcate-based authentication is required.

Answer (score -1):

With your question I understand that you already have all the required certificate and key files to use TLS authentication.

Below is a sample rsyslogd configuration to use TLS from [Configure secure remote logging with rsyslog (TLS) on Linux](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/secure-remote-logging-rsyslog-tls-certificate/)

```
# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/node3-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/node3-key.pem

$ModLoad imtcp  # TCP listener
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1  # run driver in TLS-only mode
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerRun 6514  # start up listener at port 10514
```

Here you can replace the certificate and key file locations based on your environment, if you are using a different port then change the same for `InputTCPServerRun`

The article uses GTLS as the default StreamDriver so you may have to install it manually if not already available
`$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls`

Also check SELinux and Firewall between the server and client to make sure they are not blocking the log transfer.